# what is the equivalent UpdateSystemActivity on windows

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, winapi

As the title above states, I am looking for a method like "UpdateSystemActivity" (available on Mac) which can be used to prevent the screen from locking on Windows.

I am open to languages like win32 and C#. But C/C++ would be ideal.

Thanks
Vishvesh

Comment: @Vishvesh, what do you mean by the "screen locking"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`SetThreadExecutionState()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to indicate it Windows that the system is NOT idle.

You may also want to [disable the screensaver as described here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17067/Controlling-The-Screen-Saver-With-C). It is NOT a good practice to do so without the consent of the user. A checkbox in your settings Dialog allowing the user to enable such behaviour would be most appropriate.

Comment: My use case is simple. I don't want the screen to lock when I am giving presentation, so I am writing a simple app to prevent locking of the screen as long as my app was running. Thanks.

Comment: @Vishvesh - why use a utility when Vista & Windows 7 have [Presentation Mode](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/10/28/windows-presentation-mode.aspx) built in?